# Loop through data value and assign it as a class on paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through an array of .swatch-color, get its data value and assign it to paragraph

First **lang.js**, then **lang.html**

```js
var colors = $(".swatch-color");
var dataValues = colors.data("value");
var p = $(".swatch-color p");

colors.each(function(index){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() === $(this).data("value")){
        p.addClass($(this).data("value"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colors-container">
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="black">
        <p>Black</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="blue">
        <p>Blue</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="brown">
        <p>Brown</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="clear">
        <p>Clear</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="green">
        <p>Green</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="grey">
        <p>Grey</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="light-grey">
        <p>Light Grey</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="orange">
        <p>Orange</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="pink">
        <p>Pink</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="purple">
        <p>Purple</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="red">
        <p>Red</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-color" data-value="white">
        <p>White</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I am getting this:

```
<p class="black blue brown clear green grey light-grey orange pink purple red white">Black</p>
```

I need for black value to assign "black" class, for blue "blue" etc.

Comment: I suggest that you use the debugger from the Chrome Dev Tools to find the problem. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some debugging tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing all paragraphs (`$(".swatch-color p")`) in your loop.

You want

```
$("p", this).addClass($(this).data("value"));
```

instead of

```
p.addClass($(this).data("value"));
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, that was an edit after I posted my previous comment.